# Is it possible to read QR code on macOS using webcam?

Tags: macos

I am aware of [ZBar](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar), but is there a built-in way like on iOS using the Camera app?

**Edit:** The Homebrew version of ZBar [formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/zbar) doesn't install `zbarcam` (see https://github.com/mchehab/zbar/issues/122 and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/60267#issuecomment-706600751).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `zbarcam` is not available on MacOS, but instead you can use `imagesnap` and then combine it with `zbarimg` (from zbar package).

The simplest possible solution would be:

```sh
imagesnap -w 1 snap.jpg
zbarimg -1 --raw -q -Sbinary snap.jpg
```

You can automate it to wait for first successful reading:

```sh
function scan_qr() {
  local result=""
  while true; do
    imagesnap -q -w 1 /tmp/snap.jpg
    result="$(zbarimg -1 --raw -q -Sbinary /tmp/snap.jpg)"
    [[ -n $result ]] && break
    sleep 1
  done
  echo "${result}"
}
scan_qr
```

Ready to go script, using the same mechanism, you can find [HERE](https://github.com/rynkowsg/scripts/blob/master/macos/scan-qrcode.sh).

At the top of the file you can find usage info:

```
#
# EXAMPLES:
#
#  Just print the QR code
#
#    ./scan-qrcode.sh
#
#  Copy QR code to clipboard
#
#    ./scan-qrcode.sh | pbcopy
#
#  Import paper secret key from QR code:
#
#    ./scan-qrcode.sh | paperkey --pubring public-key.asc | gpg --import
#
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This should help the OP. If the OP is reading this comment, please press the grey tick below the downvote button to show that this answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no first party solution to this in macOS and there are dozens of open source and paid apps that perform this function on macOS.

It will be interesting to see if any of the iOS and iPadOS apps provide that functionality on Apple Silicon based Macs or if Apple ships it natively before long.